# Why Blender v.4, even v4.0.2 is much slower in cycle rendering than v3.6.5?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, versions

first time i've noticed that, the first day i was installed v4 and after started to render a scene i that i make that before. it was take about 30m, and i expected something about 10 to 15 m.
I waited to release new stable versions. and in 4.0.2 i tested with a simple scene to compromise.

these are two pictures of rendering time with the exactly same setting.
and the exact same result in a same size.

[image]
[image]

render time

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXqO3.png)[image]

[image]